# Why does a LINQ statements with FirstOrDefault cause a timeout?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have LINQ statement that causes a timeout when I called the `FirstOrDefault();` method. But if I cast the results to a `List` first, the call the `FirstOrDefault();` method, it works just fine.

Why would this LINQ statement cause an SQL timeout:

```
var n = next.Where(w => w.Status == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this one work just fine?

```
var n = next.Where(w => w.Status == 1).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The main difference is that the first one will end up using a `Top 1` in the query.  Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616965/why-select-top-clause-could-lead-to-long-time-cost) that's about `TOP` causing timeouts.

Comment: The duplicate question should address your concern. If it does not, please improve your question by providing more details, including specific information about your database, [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, and an explanation of why it is that the answer explaining timeouts with `TOP` doesn't apply here.